# Call to a member function getRoles() on array while using loadByProperties()

Tags: 8, users

I am trying to check if the email provided by a user using a custom webform is already associated with an account on my site. In the case it's used, I want to get the roles of the account using that email.

I am using the following code.

```
$email = "someone@example.com";

// Loads existing Drupal user object by given email.
// Note that first matching user is returned. Email address and account name
// are unique so there can be only 'zero' or 'one' matching user when
// loading users by these properties.

// Load entities by other than entity ID.
$users = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('user')
  ->loadByProperties(['mail' => $email]);

// if 'One' user has been found matching the given email.
if (!empty($users)) {

    // Set the disabled roles.
    $disabled_roles = array ("administrator", "content_approver");

    // Loop through all roles the user has.
    // The following is the line causing the error (line 74).
    foreach ($users->getRoles() as $role) {
        // Check if the user has one or more disabled role.
        if (array_key_exists($role, $disabled_roles)) {

           // Extra codes goes here.

        }
    }
```

I get the following error.

> Error: Call to a member function getRoles() on array in Drupal\custom_module\Controller\EmailCheckController->EmailCheck() (line 74 of /home/users/public_html/example.com/web/modules/custom/custom_module/src/Controller/EmailCheckController.php)

What is wrong with my code? How can I get the roles of the user accounts I load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`EntityStorageInterface::loadByProperties()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageInterface.php/function/EntityStorageInterface%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.9.x) returns an array of objects, and it returns an array regardless of the number of results. Even if you have one result (which I am guessing is what you're expecting) you get an array back.

You can't call `getRoles()` on an array. You'll need to get the objects from the array before you do that. For example, on [`EntityStorageBase::loadByProperties`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.2.x) a commenter uses `$first_match = reset($entities);`.